# How do I define which version of matlab to use when calling command from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I have 3 versions of Matlab installed on my PC. I want to call some Matlab command from my vb.net program. So I created a Matlab object in vb.net and calls the commands. But I want to executes these commands with a specific version of matlab, let's say 2013b, using matlab command window.

How do I do it?

Comment: Use the full path of the version you want to use. Something like: `C:\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\matlab.exe`

Comment: Do you mean Dim Matlab As Object = Create("C:\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\matlab.exe")
 Something like that?

Comment: [Process.Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is how you generally start external executables.

Comment: Please show some code to explain "So I created a Matlab object in vb.net and calls the commands".  See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Do you plan to run you application where you have matlab license installed or do you plan to run on any computer?  You have to consider the run time library if running without a license.

Comment: Does this help?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-a-matlab-function-from-visual-basic-net-client.html